# HCE Excess Refund on 401k Plan

Tags: united-states, 401k, check, refund, mistakes

This year, I received a letter from the company I worked for notifying me that they did not pass the 401k non discrimination test. As a highly-compensated employee, I received an excess refund check for the 2018 year, which I cashed no problem.

I also received one the year before for 2017, but forgot to cash the check they sent me, and I no longer have that original check. Am I still able to ask for a resend of that refund check from 2 years ago, and if so, would I contact my employer or the 401k provider (in this case, Vanguard)? And assuming I am able to still get that refund, how (if at all) does this affect my tax filing for 2017?

Comment: You can always ask for the check to be reissued. It doesn’t mean you’ll definitely get it, but it’s worth trying. Did the check come from your employer or from the plan provider? That would determine who to call first to try to get it reissued. Also did you get any income statements for 2017 related to the refund? If you didn’t claim the increased income on your 2017 return then you would need to amend that return if you get the check reissued and cash it.